# Video player for H264 videos for Adam/Tegra2?

Tags: applications, video, 3.0-honeycomb, tegra, hardware-acceleration

It seems that the Adam is not fast enough to decode my H264 videos. With some players I get unsync audio, some skip video frames. Even usual PAL size (something around 500x300, far from HD). Ok, Those may have non-basic profile, but I think they are [main-profile](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) (most use CABAC, though).

The players I tried include

- MX Video Player -- best results, but can not keep up with most H264 vids
- VPlayer -- good results
- RockPlayer -- often recommended, often tried, no good results.

As you can see, all freely available ones. I *would like* buy one, If I would know that my videos are handled properly.

**Can you suggest a video player that really uses Tegra2 hardware decoding capabilities and therefore will decode the H264 videos nicely?**

(Is it important to know that I run Adamcomb on it?)

Comment: Strange that MX Video Player fumbles. I use that on my EeePad Transformer and it runs just fine, even claiming hardware decoding. Mind you, I'm doing my own encoding: 480p or 576p High Profile at 768kps.

Answer (score 1):

I first used [DicePlayer Trial](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.inisoft.mediaplayer.trial) to verify it worked properly, and the bought the [full version](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.inisoft.mediaplayer.dice), and 720p material works well on my Galaxy Tab 10.1. Give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get [**pre-alpha** builds of VLC](http://cvpcs.org/blog/2011-09-18/videolan_for_android_pre-alpha) that I have had little issue with playing just about any video format. As I said though, it is **pre-alpha**. I have tried many other apps, and most worked fairly well, but I also stream a lot of videos over my network after mounting shares to my device and none really worked with the mounted shares. VLC works fine with them.

Comment: Hm, I tried VLC, screen stays black. I guessed I'd have to wait for 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Since I put **Icecream Sandwitch** (ICS) in the *Adam* the **MX Player** definitely works best for me. It decodes most things I encoded with Handbreak in H/W-mode -- the things it can't, I am not sure why. But even some 720p/H264 stuff I could not play before are now running smoothly.